# Form of first conditional in the past

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> He throws away all the pictures that will remind him of his
>      girlfriend if he sees them

When we are talking about this event that happened in the past ,what is the correct form?

> He threw away all the pictures that would remind him of his girlfriend if
>      he saw them.

or

> He threw away all the pictures that would have reminded him of his
>      girlfriend if he had seen them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence, using the simple past tense, is better. It is simpler, correct and has the intended meaning.

The second is more complex and seems to suggest that you are talking about pictures that would remind him of his girlfriend *at that time* if he had seen them *at any time before that time*, which is not the intended meaning.

The sentence is overly complex. The easist way to fix the sentence is just to remove the "if..." clause (as it is implied by context :- how can a photo remind you of something unless you see it) Also think about the right modal verb to use.

> He threw away all the photos that (would? could? might?) remind him of his girlfriend.

If the "if he saw them" is very important then split the sentences. Don't try to make one sentence do too much work.

> If he saw some of his photos, he knew they would remind him of his girlfriend. So he threw those ones away.